# Hiding Short Description in Shop Page, WooCommerce

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, excerpt

Good morning everybody.
I am trying to remove the Short Description in the Shop Page. Doing this in the Product Page was simple enough `remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20);`

But I have found no way to do the same in the previous Shop Page. There, I just want images, not text (or at least not the Short Description, a very long tables in this case).

Could you please help me?

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry I don't know exactly what page you'll need to remove code from without seeing the website. Could you hide the specific div and leave the content for SEO purposes?

Comment: I have found a solution. Just commenting this in woocommerce/content-product.php <code> /** do_action( 'flatsome_product_box_after' ); */ </code>. This is the web: [link]http://speedrill.com/tienda/

Answer (score 1):

Try using one of the available shop loop item actions and remove call to WooCommerce template function [`woocommerce_template_single_excerpt`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_template_single_excerpt.html) using [`remove_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/).

- [`woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item) (before thumbnail)
- [`woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title) (before title)
- [`woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title) (before price)
- [`woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title) (before "Add to cart" button)
- [`woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item) (after "Add to cart" button)

These actions are called in [`woocommerce/templates/content-product.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?l=PHP&q=content-product.php&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

E. g. `remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt' );`. Make sure to match `$priority` with the `$priority` it was originally added.